# Using print format doesn't work for DictWriter in csv - python

Tags: python-3.x, csv

Below example doesn't seem to work

```
import csv

values = [{'emp_name': 'John Wick',
        'dept': 'Accounting', 'val': '10'},
       {'emp_name': 'Neo Anderson',
        'dept': 'IT', 'val': '20'}]

with open('file1.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
    fieldnames = ['name', 'department']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    for value in values:
        writer.writerow({"'name': '{emp_name}', 'department': '{dept}'".format(
            **value)
        })
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "csv_test.py", line 13, in <module>
    **value)
  File "python-3.7.5/lib/python3.7/csv.py", line 155, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "python-3.7.5/lib/python3.7/csv.py", line 148, in _dict_to_list
    wrong_fields = rowdict.keys() - self.fieldnames
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Expected Output:

```
name, department
John Wick, Accounting
Neo Anderson, IT
```

Is there a good workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pass the `dict` when using `writerow`

**Ex:**

```
import csv

values = [{'emp_name': 'John Wick',
        'dept': 'Accounting'},
       {'emp_name': 'Neo Anderson',
        'dept': 'IT'}]

with open('file1.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
    fieldnames = ['emp_name', 'dept']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    for value in values:
        writer.writerow({"emp_name": value['emp_name'], "dept": value['dept']})   #Pass the dict
```

Comment: sorry I updated the question. What I am trying to do is use just a few values from the dictionary, not even keys.

Comment: Updated snippet.

Comment: That works, I was trying to understand why **kwargs wont work. Thanks @Rakesh

Comment: I dont think writerows is still valid, so possible remove it?